# How does Alarmy App send continues local notification after App killed?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ipad, swift5

I want to know how to fire continuous local notification in ios (Swift), I run the local notification code in for loop but, when I terminate the app it will not execute full code.

Comment: You can't send local notification when your app is in kill state.

Comment: then how Alarmy app do?

Comment: are you sure they are sending local push notification

Comment: Please have a look to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988245/local-notification-on-application-termination

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Hello"
content.body = "World"
content.badge = 1
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 60, repeats: true)
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "", content: content, trigger: trigger)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: i want local notification at every 2 seconds

Comment: Notice the trigger arguments: (timeInterval: 60, repeats: true)

Comment: yes but it requires a minimum time is 60 seconds.